# Disable branding/channelinfo TwitchTV

Tags: php, html

I'm currently creating a website where I want to stream my content from. I use OBS as streaming program and TwitchTV as streaming source. What I would like to archive is to disable the branding/channelInfo from the player when .

My iframe is as following:

```
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?allowfullscreen&!branding&!channelInfo&mediaplayer&playsinline&player=site&channel=lpmassive"></iframe>
```

Or direct link to test it out for urself:
https://player.twitch.tv/?allowfullscreen&!branding&!channelInfo&mediaplayer&playsinline&player=site&channel=lpmassive

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want to remove the controls and in general when someone hovers so its just the pure video feed? You can do this by adding controls=false to the URL

Example:
https://player.twitch.tv/?allowfullscreen&!branding&!channelInfo&mediaplayer&playsinline&player=site&channel=lpmassive&controls=false